# Apache Solr multi-word keywords

Tags: solr, keyword

I want to ask if there is a descent tutorial on how to implement a multi-word keyword list with Solr.

My input-datasets include multiple titles and descriptions on a certain topic (e.g.: "Mark Aurel"). As the title and description i have multiple sources like (wikipedia & co.) with the title as the h1 and h2 and as description the text. 
Now i want to display the keywords from those sources, the best with priorities for the sources, than weighting title > description.

The Keywords should look like:

"roman emperor", "philosopher".... and so on

Got no Aaswer so here is a little more info on the topic.
The input data will come from php as an array:

```
$input[0] = array ('id' => some_md5, 'title' => 'Title Nr. 1', 'desc' => 'Desc Nr.1', 'author' => 'Mark Aurel')
$input[1] = array ('id' => some_md5, 'title' => 'Title Nr. 2', 'desc' => 'Desc Nr.2', 'author' => 'Mark Aurel')
```

Lets brake the question down to parts:

1. How can i make a multi field faceted search. Lets say over the title and desc?
2. What are the best analyzers to get meaningfull words for my Keywordlist?

Comment: Don't really understand how the data looks like and what you want to query, can you please give an example?

Comment: how do you create the query? can you provide your schema.xml? like this the question isn't much helpful...

Comment: The best schema.xml is to be found... I have just the above data stored in an array. The task is to store the values in a suitable schema so i can generate keywords, multi-word keywords and be efficient

Answer (score 0):

To search a keyword against multiple fields at once use dismax/edismax see: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax

Set the qf parameter to something like `qf=title^3 author^2 desc` this example gives title and author field more weight / importance than desc.

Comment: the query string looks like this:
q=author%3A123&facet=true&facet.field=title

now i want to add to the facet.field description. Can this be as well accomplished over extendeddismax ?

Comment: @opossum not quite sure I understand what you want. What do you mean by this? "now i want to add to the facet.field description" Ignore facets for now and just focus on the query. An edismax query would look like `http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=123&defType=edismax&qf=title^3+desc` which searches for 123 in the title and desc fields giving title more weight in the scoring.